# Why does a file not show up in the Startup folder after being copied successfully using batch?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch

I used the following code to copy a file into the startup folder

```
copy runtest.vbs "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\start-up"
```

and I know all permissions are in place since I receive the message **1 files(s) copied**

However, when I take a look inside the folder, nothing is there, and the file is not hidden.

This is Windows 10, has anyone had the same problem or know of a solution?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your syntax in the proper form?  There isn't a dash in `Startup`.  You might try something a bit shorter, also:  `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: I'm sure @Run5k has the answer: you will have created a copy of `runtest.vbs` called `start-up` in `"%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs"\ `- it is always a good idea to append a trailing back-slash when copying to a directory.

Comment: The folder is called Start-up with a dash although I have no idea why that is the case. But yes, when I removed the dash in the code, it worked out.

Comment: As @AFH emphasized in an earlier post, the existence of an object called `Start-up` (with a dash) is probably symptomatic of your previous efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have your syntax in the proper form? There isn't a dash in the name of the **Startup** folder.

You also might want to simplify your code and try something a bit shorter:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup